# Removing IRC Color-Tags

Tags: c#, colors, irc, bots

i am programing an IRC Bot with C#.
I've got a little problem with the IRC Colorcodes: Does somebody have an Idea how to remove this?

It is Like: "♥7Text" or "♥03Text and so on". Any Idea how i can remove the beginnings?
In this Example it would be necessary to remove ♥03 or ♥7...

I hope i wrote the problem clear enough...

Comment: http://www.mirc.com/colors.html

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for this Information :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/♥(\d{1,2}(,\d{1,2})?)?/
```

Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Googling shows:

http://www.mirc.com/colors.html

so you should remove anything that matches ^C, one number and possibly another number after comma.

It depends on your favorite tools how to implement it (regexps, direct checking, etc.)